# How do I bind to different property on ComboBox SelectedItem?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, selecteditem

I have a combobox in WPF like this:

```
<ComboBox Text="Select Language..." IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=item/@name, Source={StaticResource Items}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

Where Items is:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Items" Source="/itemlist.xml" XPath="/itemlist"/>
```

Test is a property of type object on ViewModel that is set as datacontext of a window.

Everything works fine, and my Test property receives XmlNode object, which makes sense.

However, I would like to receive different attribute from that xml for example `XPath=item/@value`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=VS.85).aspx) and [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=VS.85).aspx):

```
<ComboBox Text="Select Language..." IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=item, Source={StaticResource Items}}"
  DisplayMemberPath="@name"
  SelectedValuePath="@id"
  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

The selected item will be the `item` element, it will display the `name` attribute, and it will bind the `id` attribute to `Test`.

Comment: Thank! this is very sweet. I didn't know those properties supported XPath.